# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, svm, random-forest

When running the following code, I receive the error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train, X_holdout, y_train, y_holdout = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=17)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=17)

tree_params = {'max_depth': range(1,5), 'max_features': range(3,6), 'criterion': ['gini','entropy']}

tree_grid = GridSearchCV(tree, tree_params, cv=scoring='recall',average='macro')

tree_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GridSearchCV` class does not have a `average` parameter - you use it in `average='macro'`.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) of the class please:

```
class sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, *, scoring=None, n_jobs=None, iid='deprecated', refit=True, cv=None, verbose=0, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', error_score=nan, return_train_score=False)
```